# CSS Slide Transition Left to Right

Tags: jquery, css

I've been looking for a way to correct this issue I have here.

I am trying to get the two items, Toggle One and Toggle Two to be right next to each other. When I click on Toggle One, the navigation items that are attached to it should slide in, whilst pushing Toggle Two to the side at the same time.

So far, I have the animation going, but looking at the jsfiddle, you'll see that Toggle 2 will either stutter or swing wide to the right.

I am not sure what really to do, and since I need flexbox, the jQuery solutions I saw weren't working. I've already tried using a display: block and display: none, but those just shoot right out and just show, so I've had to use visibility and opacity.

The width also cannot be set as the content displayed will need to be dynamic based on the content entered.

```js
(function($) {
  function toggleNav($thisChild) {
    var $child = $thisChild,
      $toggle = $child.siblings('.toggle');

    if ($toggle.hasClass('opened-nav'))
      $toggle.removeClass('opened-nav');
    else
      $toggle.addClass('opened-nav');

    if ($child.hasClass('open'))
      $child.removeClass('open');
    else
      $child.addClass('open');

  };

  $('#controller-one').on('click', function() {
    $('#controller-two').removeClass('opened-nav');
    $('#nav-two').removeClass('open');
    toggleNav($('#nav-one'));
  })

  $('#controller-two').on('click', function() {
    $('#controller-one').removeClass('opened-nav');
    $('#nav-one').removeClass('open');
    toggleNav($('#nav-two'));
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```css
p,
li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  height: 55px;
  background: #294251;
}

#controller-one,
#controller-two {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

#controller-one {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 102;
  background: #294251;
}

#controller-two {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 101;
  background: #294251;
}

.toggle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toggle-one {
  background: #4082ca;
}

#toggle-two {
  background: #245e93;
}

.toggle p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.toggle p:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  height: 2px;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.navigation.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(0);
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navigation ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navigation li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
  <div id="controller-one">
    <nav id="toggle-one" class="toggle">
      <p>T One</p>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navigation" id="nav-one">
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="controller-two">
    <nav id="toggle-two" class="toggle">
      <p>T Two</p>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navigation" id="nav-two">
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**May be this could help**

I made some update in your work.

```js
(function($) {
 function toggleNav($thisChild) {
  var $child = $thisChild,
  $toggle = $child.siblings('.toggle');
  
  if ($toggle.hasClass('opened-nav'))
   $toggle.removeClass('opened-nav');
  else
   $toggle.addClass('opened-nav');
  
  if ($child.hasClass('open'))
   $child.removeClass('open');
  else
   $child.addClass('open');
 }

 $('#controller-one').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("sub-active").siblings().removeClass("sub-active");
  $('#controller-two').removeClass('opened-nav');
  $('#nav-two').removeClass('open');
  toggleNav($('#nav-one'));
 });
 
 $('#controller-two').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("sub-active").siblings().removeClass("sub-active");
  $('#controller-one').removeClass('opened-nav');
  $('#nav-one').removeClass('open');
  toggleNav($('#nav-two'));
 });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
p, li {
 padding: 0 10px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
.controls {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 align-items: center;
 height: 55px;
 background: #294251;
}
#controller-one, #controller-two {
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 align-items: center;
 transition: all .4s;
 flex-basis: 3.97em;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#controller-one.sub-active, #controller-two.sub-active {
 flex-basis: 16em;
 -ms-flex-preferred-size: 16em;
}
#controller-one {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 102;
 background: #294251;
}
#controller-two {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 101;
 background: #294251;
}
.toggle {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 100;
 height: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#toggle-one {
 background: #4082ca;
}
#toggle-two {
 background: #245e93;
}
.toggle p {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
}
.toggle p:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 height: 2px;
}
.navigation {
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
 align-items: center;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 margin-left: -100%;
 transition: all 0.4s;
}
.navigation.open {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
 margin-left: 0;
 transition: all 0.6s;
}
.navigation ul {
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.navigation li {
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
    <div id="controller-one">
        <nav id="toggle-one" class="toggle">
            <p>T One</p>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navigation" id="nav-one">
            <ul>
                <li>item 1</li>
                <li>item 2</li>
                <li>item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="controller-two">
        <nav id="toggle-two" class="toggle">
            <p>T Two</p>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navigation" id="nav-two">
            <ul>
                <li>item 1</li>
                <li>item 2</li>
                <li>item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but for the most part. The only issue is `#controller-one, #controller-two { flex-basis: 3.97em; }` as this will not allow the toggle text to be dynamic in width :\

Comment: I will accept the answer, and if you have a suggestion on how to make the width dynamic on the above, I'd appreciate it! This is 99% what I needed!

Comment: @Ishio , Thanks . I will try ma best . I will let you know if i have solution.